# WPF animation only works in one direction

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm making a "traffic light" animation controlled by radiobuttons in xaml. I'm using an ellipse style to change the color and animate the movement. The problem is, the animation only works when the ellipse is moving down (to a higher value of Canvas.Top), but doesn't work when it's moving up (to a lower value of Canvas.Top).

Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="hw05.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:hw05"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RedRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="83">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=YellowRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="133">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GreenRB}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" Duration="0:0:0.400" To="183">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Canvas>
        <RadioButton Name="RedRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="True" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100">first</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="YellowRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150">second</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="GreenRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="200">third</RadioButton>
        <Ellipse Name="Light" Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="83"></Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why don't you just set `From`?

Comment: Because the From value would need to change according to where the Ellipse is and I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that triggers like `Trigger`and `DataTrigger` are state based: you have an enter action to reflect the transition *to* the state (e.g., `IsChecked`: `false` => `true`) and an exit action to reflect the transition *from* the state (e.g., `IsChecked`: `true` => `false`). You are currently only defining an animation for the entering transition. So from the animation's perspective the entering state is never left. `DataTrigger.EnterAction` will hold the animation state until `DataTrigger.ExitAction` was executed => state based.

In your scenario it makes more sense to trigger the animation event based: the animation is executed when a certain event occurred (e.g., `RadioButton.Checked`) and on hold until the next event occurred. Each animation animates the values of the previous animation (if `FillBehavior="Hold"`, which is the default).

The following example has moved the animation to the `Canvas` as this defines a common name scope of all participating elements:

```
<Canvas>
  <RadioButton Name="RedRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="True" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="100">first</RadioButton>
  <RadioButton Name="YellowRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="150">second</RadioButton>
  <RadioButton Name="GreenRB" GroupName="One" IsChecked="False" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="200">third</RadioButton>
  <Ellipse Name="Light" 
           Fill="Red" 
           Width="50" Height="50" 
           Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="83"  />


  <Canvas.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RadioButton.Checked" SourceName="RedRB">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                           Storyboard.TargetName="Light" 
                           Duration="0:0:0.400" To="83" />
          <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                          Storyboard.TargetName="Light"
                          To="Red" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RadioButton.Checked" SourceName="YellowRB">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                           Storyboard.TargetName="Light" 
                           Duration="0:0:0.400" To="133" />
          <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                          Storyboard.TargetName="Light"
                          To="Yellow" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="RadioButton.Checked" SourceName="GreenRB">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)" 
                           Storyboard.TargetName="Light" 
                           Duration="0:0:0.400" To="183" />
          <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                          Storyboard.TargetName="Light"
                          To="Green" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Canvas.Triggers>
</Canvas>
```